# Implementing TASK delay

Tags: assembly, delay, dos, tasm, dosbox

Can anyone give me advice how can I implement simple to use ASM delay?
Nop is bad way cuz it depends from CPU.
Int 15h function 86h is bad too cuz it is blocking other interrupts (like 09h).

Comment: Hook interrupt 8 (the system timer interrupt), and you'll get interrupts at 18.2 Hz.

Comment: @Michael, Hmm, with int 8 most minimal delay can be 55ms or I can generate lesser than 55ms?

Comment: You can write to ports 0x40 and 0x43 to alter the timer prescalar, which changes the frequency (see e.g. http://www.inversereality.org/tutorials/interrupt%20programming/timerinterrupt.html).

Comment: Everything about timing on the PC family under DOS by Kris Heidenstrom:
http://www.phatcode.net/res/246/files/pctim003.txt

Comment: And together with using the timer interrupt (with default 18.2) and with our own temporary ISR for to do a measurement with switching a value of a selected register that we use as a flag for to signal that one second is done, we can let our main routine execute a loop with a mix of instructions inside(example 64 nop´s in a very simple form) and additional with using a counter for to count how much rounds we had done in one second and in consequence we can perform a delay for different rapid CPU´s with the multiple of this counter. (Switching timer int back to its previous vector address.)

Comment: + delay with polling port 0x3DA